# What is the difference between yeast nutrient and yeast accelerator?

Tags: yeast, cider, yeast-nutrient

I know what yeast nutrient is, but was browsing around the brew supply and noticed yeast accelerator. Anyone know that the REAL difference (if any) is chemically? See it mentioned through a goggle search, but not certain what it actually does. Does it shorten the fermentation time by enhancing the yeast metabolism rate? Are there downsides if this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: There's a table in The Compleat Meadmaker that breaks that down, but I don't have the book handy at the moment.   I think one is more DAP (Diammonium Phosphate) and Zinc, and the other is more FAN (Free Amino Nitrogen), but I don't remember which is which.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into getting that reference, sounds like a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeast nutrient is used primarily to ensure a strong fermentation and is typically added toward the end of boil. Yeast accelerator is used to fix a stalled fermentation. Each contains various ingredients like phosphates and minerals to help in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yeast nutrient is "vitamins and minerals" to help yeast grow and ferment.

Yeast energizer is like "speed" to kick start a stuck fermentation.